# checking if an endomorphism is self-adjoint.

Tags: linear-algebra, self-adjoint-operators

> Let $V$ be an inner product space and let $\alpha$ be an endomorphism of $V$. Is the endomorphism $\alpha^*\alpha - \sigma_1$ of $V$ self-adjoint?

Could anyone give me a hint on how to check this?

Comment: For future reference, it is preferred to post questions with LaTeX formatting rather than pictures as the latter is not as accessible to readers.

Comment: What have you tried? What does it mean for an operator to be self-adjoint?

Comment: What is $\sigma_1$?

Comment: An endomorphism, $T$, is *self-adjoint* if it satisfies $T^* = T$. So, just check that $$(\alpha^* \alpha - \sigma_1)^* = \alpha^* \alpha - \sigma_1.$$

Comment: I agree with @KaboMurphy - what is $\sigma_1$ in this context?

Comment: @kabo Murphy it is the identity map

Comment: @Math1000  Murphy it is the identity map